# Best way to connect Yamaha mixer to powered Harbinger loudspeakers

Tags: mixer

Should hopefully have a few simple questions, but in my research I haven't quite found the exact answer I was looking for.  So I have a Yamaha mg10xu mixer and two Harbinger V2312 powered speakers.

[image]

[image]

Reading the Harbinger manual, it suggests to chain the two speakers together to make one the master.  With this configuration I am not quite sure what the best way would be to connect the mixer to the speakers.  Right now I am using the L Monitor Out into the master speaker in channel 3.  It seems to sound good to me, but I was wondering if this would be the optimal connection?

We originally had the two XLR Stero Out connections going to their respective speaker, but this seems like it will make the pair separate, if that makes sense.  We also like the Bluetooth capabilities of these speakers, which I would think the only way to get sound to come out of both would be to chain them and connect via Bluetooth to the master.

Would it be better to use, let's say, the L XLR out to the XLR input on the master and leave them chained?  I don't think this would work, since I would have to change the input switch to line, which would remove it as master.  Should we go back to having an XLR out to each speaker?

One final question for connections, I have a POD HD500 that I have connected to the mixer.  Right now I am using channel 2, I believe, with a 1/4" connector going out the mono L on the POD.  This also seems to sound good with our current setup, but was curious if anyone had any experience with the POD and what the recommendations might be for that as well.

Many thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now I am using the L Monitor Out into the master speaker in channel 3. It seems to sound good to me, but I was wondering if this would be the optimal connection?

I think that will be fine, but it will be in mono. If you want stereo, then also connect the right monitor out to the  'Right' input in channel 3.

[image]

> One final question for connections, I have a POD HD500 that I have connected to the mixer. Right now I am using channel 2, I believe, with a 1/4" connector going out the mono L on the POD. This also seems to sound good with our current setup, but was curious if anyone had any experience with the POD and what the recommendations might be for that as well.

Again, that sounds fine if you want mono, but plug the right output into another mixer channel (and pan accordingly) if you want stereo! Or you could plug L/R into one of the stereo mixer channels, or if you have a long cable run and some spare XLR cables, you could try using those instead (As the HD500 seems to have XLR outs too).

Comment: Ah, so both the L and R connections would go to the master speaker and the chain connection would pass the sound to the secondary speaker.  I'm guessing then that the V2312 is smart enough to know which sounds to send to left and right when you have the master-to-line setup properly.

I guess another option could be to take the stereo L/R XLR outputs on the mixer and then connect to channel 1 and 2 on the master speaker.  Would this work as well?  I've been playing guitar for many years, but this is my first go around to actually learn how things are setup for live shows, etc.  Cool stuff!

Comment: "I'm guessing then that the V2312 is smart enough to know which sounds to send to left and right when you have the master-to-line setup properly" - I think that's the idea, yes. I don't have these speakers BTW - I'm just giving my impression of what it says in the manual, so please take my advice accordingly!

Comment: "I guess another option could be to take the stereo L/R XLR outputs on the mixer and then connect to channel 1 and 2 on the master speaker. Would this work as well?" - I don't think that would give you stereo, because I don't see anything 'L' or 'R' specific on channel 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks so much for the useful (and very fast) responses.  Next time at band practice I may tinker around a bit, but I'm glad to know that my current connection will do the trick.  I'll mark yours as the answer, unless anyone else has anything else to add.